# Appending and reading binary file

Tags: c++, binary, append

I am confused as to where in my code am I getting it wrong. Instead of resulting to 1,2,3 the output is 1,1,1. Any suggestions as to what I can do? I am guessing my error lies either in the writing data or when I use the variable value.

```
class Binary
{
 public:
   Binary(int num);
  ~Binary();

  void createBinary();
  void writeBinary();
  void readBinary();

  string binFile;
  int value;
  fstream binaryFile;
};

Binary::Binary(int num)
{
 value = num;
 binFile = "BinaryFile.bin";
}

Binary::~Binary()
{
}

void Binary::createBinary()
{
  binaryFile.open(binFile, ios::out | ios::binary);
  binaryFile.close();
}

void Binary::writeBinary()
{
  if (!binaryFile) //if file does not exist
  {
    createBinary();
  }

  binaryFile.open(binFile, ios::app | ios::binary);
  binaryFile.write((char*)&value, sizeof(value));
  binaryFile.close();
}

void Binary::readBinary()
{

  binaryFile.open(binFile, ios::in |ios::binary);
  binaryFile.read((char*)&value, sizeof(value));
  binaryFile.close();

  cout << value << ", ";
}



int main()
{
  Binary num1(1);
  Binary num2(2);
  Binary num3(3);

  num1.writeBinary();
  num2.writeBinary();
  num3.writeBinary();

  num1.readBinary();
  num2.readBinary();
  num3.readBinary();


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: which part of the file does `readBinary()` read each of the three times it is called? Your multiple choice answers are: 1. Somehow it magically knows what part of the file previous calls to `readBinary()` have read, and it skips ahead to the following part of the file, or 2. Always the beginning of the file. You have 30 seconds to come up with an answer. The clock starts ticking ...now.

Comment: To put it more simple: Open the file once, read from it repeatedly, then close it.

Comment: It should read at the beginning of the file

Comment: Right. So, why are you surprised that every time `readBinary()` is called, it reads the same value from the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a single file and read from start at each Binary()::readBinary(), your result is as expected. Either use different files for each of your objects.

```
// In general we may need some random part in name but for this special case,
// since you are just writing / reading value, the following seems to work.

Binary::Binary(int num)
{
    value = num;
    binFile = "BinaryFile";    // common start
    binFile += std::to_string(value);    // differentiator
    binFile += ".bin";    // extension
}
```

Or, if you want to use the same file, try to get help from a static variable for not to read the same line again and again.